# Pros/Cons of anonymity in a modern democracy?

Tags: democracy

I recently watched an interview with Richard Stallman and in which he says something like "We need anonymity to make democracy safe"

I can see that there's a trade-off between privacy and security/safety but...

What other factors can we weigh in when evaluating the pros/cons of anonymity in a democracy?

In order to narrow this question and avoid rambling about the definition of concepts let's assume the following:

**Definitions**

- *Democracy* - the most common form of democracy practiced today, i.e., a mix of representative democracy with a little bit of oligarchy and monarchist chips on top.
- *Safety* - Safety of the individual
- *Anonymity* - I would like to consider a broad sense of the term, right now I can think of two senses: monetary anonymity and anonymity of opinion, tough there may be more that are also relevant.

Comment: are you asking specifically about anonymity in the exercise of democracy (I.e. voting, juries) or what Stallman was speaking of, monetary anonymity (so the government can't track what you buy). The former might be quite odd in certain situations (can you run for office anonymously?, can votes in congress be anonymous?), and the latter has good (purchase/selling of contraband, tax evasion, political retribution (that is why politicians pay hookers in cash), ...). Do you mean direct democracy (people vote), or representative democracy (republic), or something else?

Comment: You also have a title/body mismatch. Do you want to know if democracy requires anonymity, of what are the advantages/disadvantages of anonymity in a democracy. (I think you want the latter.)

Comment: can I presume that you're talking of anonymity of votes? or are you talking about the anonymity of other things too?

Comment: @user1873 Thanks for your comments, I have edited the question, hopefully this will help get more concrete answers.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla, you actually made it worse. You included some "pro" arguments. Questions shouldn't contain Answers. "What other factors **should we weigh** in when evaluating the pros/cons of anonymity in a democracy?" In general, Politics.SE doesn't like **should**. Even of we read this as, "what factors contribute to anonymity being beneficial/detrimental in a democracy." It might be too broad (list of things).

Comment: @user1873 I have removed the answers, and change the wording. And I don't mind if the list is too broad, that's exactly the point. Previously my view was narrower since I had only considered the privacy-safety trade-off. Now I know that anonymity enables objectivity which is something I didn't think about before. Do you have any other suggestions on how to improve the question?

Comment: This kind of open-ended question is not at all a fit for SE.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, you didn't specify whether you're interested in anonymity of voting or anonymity of opinion expression. Those may have somewhat different reasons.

Democracy is a form of government in which all eligible citizens participate equally. As such, anything that prevents someone from expressing their political opinion or voting is detrimental to democracy.

There are at least 3 reasons anonymity is important to a healthy democracy based in **real life**, in a sesnse that without anonymity, people would be prevented from said expression of their political opinion:

1. **Anonymity allows people to express political views that they are afraid would cause them social fallout of various kind**.

   I would never openly state my support for drug legalization because I don't want my current/future employers finding that out about me (and unlike many legalization supporters, I never even tried any drugs at all).

   Hollywood blacklisted left leaning people for a brief period, to be replaced by blacklisting right leaning period these days.

   People - especially those on the left - view boycotts and campaigns against people's livelihoods a very valid political tool. Read Alinsky's book for more formal grounding in this.

   Of course, in less civilized societies, people were worried more about being killed than merely socially ostracized. From Kings beheading anyone opposing them to Socialist totalitarian leaders killing off millions in last century.
2. **Anonymity allows people to avoid physical intimidation from those opposing their political views**.

   In short, it stop the strong from ruling over the weak, whether the strength is via simple physical mass/size, skill at fighting, sociopathic personality, wealth to hire the strength of others, or sheer numbers.

   As an example, this has been the biggest point in the recent US debates about "Card check" legislation (which would force people to vote for/against the union in non-anonymous way).

   Or I can post a representative sample of comments wishing physical harm on people of certain political persuasion in comments on web sites of opposite political persuasion.

   Or I can simply point you to a nearest history book [for one of the most famous cases of violence in US politics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr%E2%80%93Hamilton_duel).

   Or you can peruse the [very helpful answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/10469/332) a sister Stack Exchange site has about violence in the halls of US Congress.
3. **Anonymous expression allows us to disassociate the post from the user**, to repeat Stack Exchange mantra stemming from identical idea.

   It lets people judge political opinion on its merits, without being biased by Ad Hominem attacks (*"you don't really want to listed to Stallman's opinion, because he rarely bathes and is a smelly unkempt hippie"*. "*Anyone against Obamacare is wrong because they are against it due to being racist*".)

Of course, this was known long time ago, as evidenced by the fact that many founding fathers posted tons of stuff anonymously.

An interesting read is: **Anonymity and Democratic Citizenship** (James A. Gardner,
SUNY Buffalo Law School; Florida State University - College of Law, January 1, 2011, William & Mary Bill of Rights, Vol. 19 Buffalo Legal Studies Research Paper No. 2011-008). SSRN link [here](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1743742) for those who wish to read and have SSRN account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is very informative. Though, it seems to me that the first two aren't really different reasons, voting is an expression of your opinion. You can extend this argument to say that buying something is also expressing your opinion. Would you say it is fair to collapse the two first reasons in favor of anonymity as "Anonymity reduces the risk of harm for expressing your opinion"? And would you agree that the third reason can be understood as "Anonymity enables objectivity"?

Comment: @pgpb.padilla - I view physical threats as somewhat different from social ones, though you can lump them together under certain philosophical structures.

Comment: Very good answer. +1 to distinguish the theory (full disclosure the better) vs the practice (or real life).

Comment: which alinksy book, share the title of the book, author in full and year of publication (if possible) please.

Answer (score 2):

It's a slight variant of the first point made by DVK (+1) but anonymity is important, not only to avoid intimidation but also make corruption a bit more difficult. In some countries, the anonymity of the vote is therefore not only allowed or protected but actually mandated.

For example, in France, if you mark your ballot paper in any way that make it recognizable, it should not be counted. So even if you would want to, you have no practical way to prove you did actually vote for someone and be rewarded or threatened for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Relaxed. Could you elaborate a little bit more on how corruption can be avoided by making the vote anonymous. The way I see it is the other way around, it is easier to manipulate the results if they are anonymous and you have a corrupted vote-counting system.

Comment: @pgpb.padilla Not entirely avoided but made a bit more difficult. If you are paying someone for their vote, you want to have a way to verify they do actually vote for you, otherwise you could give them money and still get nothing in return. So you could ask them to put some discrete mark on their ballot paper that everyone could see when the votes are counted, thus breaking the anonymity. That's what's forbidden. Obviously, you need to protect the integrity of the vote-counting system as well but that's necessary in any case.

Answer (score -1):

From what I've read into this thus far, the principle of anonymity is most-critical when voting.

Identity **during** evaluation of a vote is extremely important, for obvious reasons of forging ballots.

---

People will tend to withhold 'free opinion' during discourse for fear they explore or represent ideas that run counter to their public image.  Anonymity safeguards against *'compromising one's identity'* during development periods.

Pardon that I can't cite this statement; i've seen it much, but can't think of the sources offhand.  An analogue exists within much of the EU's laws regarding *children*, particularly in Spain, where freedom from their identity being documented during development years safeguards their psychological development.

---

I feel strongly that the issue with Anonymity in the US, England, and maybe others, is that citizens have lost trust in their governments, and this doubt what wrong actions could be done by using information regarding a person's identity.

Anonymity gives some protection against that, but since you eventually have to take the mask off to be accountable, this ideology fails along the way - which probably has stripped power from contemporary reform movements.

Comment: -1 not because I disagree, but because I've no clue what you are talking about. It's way too confused for me, though I'm not sure it's just me or it is actually messed up.

Comment: If you're willing to admit your own uncertainty, then why chastise someone else for that?

Comment: "rambling" is the cause of the downvote, I think.

Comment: _"Identity during evaluation of a vote is extremely important, for obvious reasons of forging ballots."_ They could just give everybody one voting token. In other words, there are other ways to avoid voter fraud without taking away important voter anonymity? As long as the same person doesn't vote twice, we don't need to know who that person is.

Comment: @BarryLandis Well, we do need to know that the person we gave it to is the person who used it.  The token is not biologically inseparable from the voter.

Answer (score -1):

No we totally don't need it, though **OF COURSE** *"if you change something here, you need to change something else there"*.

Current society is partly based on the assumption that the votes are secret, so while a society with non-secret votes may be designed (and I would personally agree it would be a great thing to do), "just removing secrecy" from this one without changing anything else would likely be very bad.

Comment: So what else needs to be changed?  You are not providing any form of analysis in you 'answer'.

Comment: "lol" i did not downvote you.

Comment: @NewAlexandria in that case, I apologise

Comment: _(it's all SE's fault, I've always stated votes should not be secret)_

Comment: _LOL_ ... what factors should we consider wen evaluating the pros and cons of anonymity in SE? ... _LOL_

Comment: @pgpb.padilla look at videosift.com, it perfectly works with public votes.